# Python __init__ error if not there

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way to throw an error if there is no **init**.

```
class test(object):

    def __init__ (self,amount):
        try:    
            self.orig_amount = amount
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError("There must be an amount entered")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x = test()
```

I would like this to throw an error saying that there needs to be an amount entered into test()

Comment: What's wrong with the error Python gives you, `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`? You just want a different message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
class test(object):

    def __init__ (self,amount = None): #Unless None is a valid amount, use any default value that is not permissible
        if amount is None:
            raise TypeError("There must be an amount entered")
        self.orig_amount = amount
```

This way you get your custom error raised, and not the generic "wrong argument count" error.

Comment: That should really be `if amount is None:`

Comment: Why allow amount to be a default variable equal to `None` if that's not a valid parameter? Shouldn't you make it required and just check for its type?

Comment: @Jay Don't ask me. Ask OP.

Comment: @jonrsharpe For which value of `a` except `None` evaluates the following to True: `a == None`?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: `class stupid(object): def __eq__(self, other): if other is None: return True`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: @SteveJessop Haha. I was just editing my question, excluding "stupid classes" with senseless `__eq__`.